# How to make an addition in jquery?

Tags: jquery, operators, addition

**What I'm trying to do:**

How can I distinguish the jquery operator (+) which is used to concatenate elements, from the + sign which is used to add elements ?

**What I've tried so far**

Here, I try to add the values of two inputs. In my code, more complex, the result is the same, it does not add but concatenates the elements..

Here is my code, I can"t see what's wrong here

```js
a=$('#a').val()+'px';
b=$('#b').val()+'px';

c=(a+b);


  $('#result').html(c);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 
<input id="a" type="number" value="10">

<input id="b" type="number" value="10">


<output id="result"></output>
```

Comment: You're concatenating concatenated strings. You need `c=(parseInt(a)+parseInt(b));`

Comment: And don't concate the inputs with `'px'` before adding them

Comment: What exactly did you think "123px" plus "456px" would be?  It's not a number because it has "px".   Did you want to add the 123+456 *then* add the px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=$('#a').val(); b=$('#b').val(); 
c= parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)+'px';    
$('#result').html(c);
```

> use parseInt to plus

Comment: thanks a lot, Iit works with parseint !