# How to add in jquery with text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> How can I perform addition or subtraction on number with text in jQuery?
>
> I have some  values with text. I want to use jQuery to add these values .

Here us the   values which i want to add :-

45px + 50px  and want  result     95px

Comment: this may help  you :-  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75969873/how-to-make-an-addition-in-jquery/75969951#75969951

Comment: @LalitKumar that will not work if hes text contains 'px'

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this**

```js
var v1 = "45px";
var v2 = "50px";

var add = parseInt(v1) + parseInt(v2);
var result = add + "px";

console.log(result);
```

`parseInt` converts to a number and that allows you to do the math.
See [MDN: JavaScript docs - parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Answer (score 0):

This is a not way to do but for your knowledge, Try to use  parseFloat('45px') + parseFloat('50px') after you getting result in INT then you need to append 'px' with that calculate value. as exmaple 95 + 'px'.

Comment: You can create a runnable snippet with the `<>` button to demonstrate your solution. Why not use parseInt as one of the other answers show? There are no decimal values here.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JavaScript function that can take a series of pixel strings (like `95px`), add them together, and return a new string.

Here a series of arguments is coerced to an array (rest parameters). Using `reduce` to iterate over that array we take each string, grab the number using [a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions), and add it to the reducer's accumulator (which starts at zero).

Finally a new string is returned using that summed number.

```js
const s1 = '45px';
const s2 = '50px';
const s3 = '10px';
const s4 = '5px';

// Accept list of pixel strings which you can coerce
// to an array with rest params
function addPixelNumbers(...pixelStrings) {

  // Create a sum by reducing over the strings,
  // and for each use a regex to extract the digits
  // coerce it to a number, and add it to the accumulator
  const sum = pixelStrings.reduce((acc, c) => {
    return acc + Number(c.match(/\d+/));
  }, 0);

  // Finally return a new string formed from the sum
  return `${sum}px`;
}

console.log(addPixelNumbers(s1, s2, s3, s4))
```

Additional documentation

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)